# What genre is Bob Bradley's "Stand My Ground"?

Tags: identify-this-genre

Recently found this song, Bob Bradley's "Stand My Ground", I'm unsure of the genre.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZAG32-oveU

Also if anyone has any more information on the artist that would be great too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds like simply Rock to me.

Comment: Yeah that's rock.

Answer (score 1):

The genre of this song is **Rock**.

[**Bob Bradley**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Bradley_(composer)) is a music composer who works for the music catalogue [Audio Network](http://us.audionetwork.com). Here is a [list of his tracks](http://us.audionetwork.com/browse/m/composer/Bob-Bradley_117).

He co-signed the song [*Stand My Ground*](http://us.audionetwork.com/browse/m/track/stand-my-ground_56782) with Matt Sanchez, Steve Dymond and Giuseppe De Luca.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pop song (lighter vocals, bouncy rhythm, bubbly synthesizers) with some minor ska influences (the strong chord on the upbeat in some sections).  Although like most modern pop, it has rock influences, it doesn't have the driving beat or the electric guitar (or piano) focus that characterizes most rock.